# How to read string in text file then loop to another string?

Tags: c++, loops, text, getline

I have been tackling this problem for almost two sleepless(?) weeks now. I'm creating a program that will read from a text file and prints getline() with a period '.' delimiter. I want to read each sentence AND also check for the strings "[INT]" and the like.

This program is a rudimentary text-based visual novel, and thus needs choices, stats and save algorithms.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

#define KEY_UP 72
#define KEY_DOWN 80
#define KEY_LEFT 75
#define KEY_RIGHT 77
#define ENTER 13
#define ESC 27
#define BACKSPACE 8

int main()
{
    if(!loadfile)
    {
        cout<<"\n\n[Load a Saved File First.]\n\n\n\n";
        system("pause");
        //loadgame();                unimportant for now
    }
    menu = true;
    system("cls");
    ifstream novel("Novels\\main.vnt");
    fstream backlog;
    backlog.open("backlog.txt");
    pagex=0;
  /*while(pagex!=page)
    {
        //loop until pagex = page
    }*/
    string title = "title ", line;
    getline(novel, line);
    system(("title "+line).c_str());
    while(menu)
    {
        c=0;
        switch((c=getch()))
        {
            case KEY_DOWN:
                getline(novel, line, '.');
                line += ".";
                backlog<<line;
                page++;
                cout<<line;
                break;
            case KEY_UP:
                while(getline(backlog, logline))
                {
                    cout<<logline;
                    system("pause");
                }
                break;
            //case 's':
            //case 'S':
            //    savegame(1, 's');     unimportant for now
            case ESC:
                menu = false;
                //goto character;       unimportant for now
                break;
            case ENTER:
                /*In this part, the code should loop (using page as a counter)
                  until it reaches one of the special formats (like "[INT]", 
                  "[PAT]", "[CHOICE]" and so on*/
                break;
        }
    //character:
        //character();                  unimportant for now
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

As for the format of the story:

> Hello there.
>
> [CHOICE]:
>
> > [INT]: I'm so smart.
> >
> > [PAT]: I'm so patient.
> >
> > [CHR]: I'm so charming.
> >
> > [SAN]: I'm so sane.
>
> [INT](
>
> Yeah, right. I can't even finish this sente
>
> )
>
> [PAT}(
>
> Yeah, right. You do know you should pass this tomorrow, right?
>
> )
>
> [CHR](
>
> Yeah, right. Why does my heart beat fast?
>
> )
>
> [SAN](
>
> Hurr, durr.
>
> )

I've tried reading a line and saving it instead rather than using a number, but due to the sentence-based printing, I can't just up and save a line and expect the user to understand where he left off when he reads

"ere are you?", said the maid. Apparently, standardiza"

Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You want to parse for [X] in the text? You want to know how to read and store your story in some data structure?

Comment: I already know how to store the stats via serialization. Yes, what I want to do is to parse for [x] in the text while in getline(novel, line, '.') only. I tried nested getlines ( while(getline(novel, line)) { stringstream temp << line; while(getline(temp, line, '[')) ) but to no avail

Comment: Maybe you could use regex?

Comment: There are a lot of [INT]s and [CHOICE]s. What's more, there will be nested [CHOICE]s. I suppose I can read the [CHOICE] until the closing clause, but then the page variable will be screwed and unable to load correctly once saved. Is there a roundabout this? I like the usage of regex.